# I cant delete data from mysql through id

Tags: php, mysql, database

I dont know where i am getting an error but i am not able to delete the row by id.Here is my code.I have made only delete script not edit script so please ignore it.

```
<?php include "includes/connection.php";?>
<?php include "includes/header.php";?>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['menu_submit'])){
        $item_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_name']);
        $item_link = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_link']);

        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO navbar (navbar_title, navbar_link) values('$item_name', '$item_link')";

        if($item_name=="" || $item_link==""){
            $required = '<div class="error">All Fields are Required</div>';
        }
        else{
            if(mysql_query($insert_query)){
                $added = '<div class="success">Menu Item Added Successfully</div>';
            }
            else{
                $failed = '<div class="error">Failed to Add Menu Item</div>';
            }
        }
    }
?>

            <div id="content">
                <h2>Add Menu Item</h2>
                <?php  if(isset($added)){echo $added;} ?>
                <?php  if(isset($failed)){echo $failed;} ?>
                <?php  if(isset($required)){echo $required;} ?>
                <form method="post" action="add_menu.php">
                    Menu item Name: <input type="text" name="item_name">
                    Menu item Link: <input type="text" name="item_link">
                    <input type="submit" name="menu_submit" value="Add Item Now">
                </form>
                </br>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item Name</th>
                        <th>Item Link</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Options</th>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                    $run_query = "SELECT * From navbar";
                    $get_query = mysql_query($run_query);

                    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($get_query)){
                        $get_item_id = $rows['navbar_id'];
                        $get_item_name = $rows['navbar_title'];
                        $get_item_link = $rows['navbar_link'];
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $get_item_name; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $get_item_link; ?></td>
                        <td><a href="add_menu.php?edit=<?php echo $get_item_id; ?>">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href="add_menu.php?delete=<?php echo $get_item_id; ?>">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php }?>
                </table>
            </div>
<?php include "includes/footer.php";?>
```

Here is my delete script and please ignore the edit script i am working on it.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['edit'])){$edit_item_id = $_GET['edit'];}
    if(isset($_GET['delete'])){$delete_item_id = $_GET['delete'];}

    $delete_query = 'DELETE FROM navbar where id="$delete_item_id"';
    if(mysql_query($delete_query)){
        $item_deleted = '<div class="success">Item has been Deleted</div>';
    }
    else{
        $item_not_deleted = '<div class="error">Item did not Deleted Successfully</div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for the wrong variable if it is set

Change this

```
if(isset($edit_item_id)){$edit_item_id = $_GET['edit'];}
if(isset($delete_item_id)){$delete_item_id = $_GET['delete'];}
```

To this

```
if(isset($_GET['edit'])) $edit_item_id = $_GET['edit'];
if(isset($_GET['delete'])) $delete_item_id = $_GET['delete'];
```

Also, you are vulnerable to SQL Injection
Please make sure you validate, sanitize your variables and start using MySQLi

Answer (score 0):

error in query:

```
$delete_query = 'DELETE FROM navbar where id="$delete_item_id"';
```

instead use:

```
$delete_query = "DELETE FROM navbar WHERE id='$delete_item_id'";
```

EDIT:

change these two lines:

```
if(isset($_GET['edit'])){$edit_item_id = $_GET['edit'];}
if(isset($_GET['delete'])){$delete_item_id = $_GET['delete'];}
```

Comment: then i get this error and still it didn't work "Notice: Undefined variable: delete_item_id in E:\Xampp\htdocs\Company_Corp\admin\add_menu.php on line 64"

Comment: I added some to my answer, you GET variables weren't loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're checking for the $delete_item_id, I think you meant to check and see if a value has been passed through using the $_GET.

Secondly, you need to make sure the string being created allows variables. I personally prefer concatenating them in.

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET['delete'])){$delete_item_id = $_GET['delete'];}

    $delete_query = "DELETE FROM navbar where id=" . $delete_item_id ."";
    if(mysql_query($delete_query)){
        $item_deleted = '<div class="success">Item has been Deleted</div>';
    }
    else{
        $item_not_deleted = '<div class="error">Item did not Deleted Successfully</div>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

how about this?

```
$delete_query = "DELETE FROM navbar WHERE id='{$delete_item_id}'";
```

also:

```
if(!isset($delete_item_id)){$delete_item_id = $_GET['delete'];}
```

notice a little change here as well...

Comment: this i get this error "Notice: Undefined variable: delete_item_id in E:\Xampp\htdocs\Company_Corp\admin\add_menu.php on line 64"

Comment: I think DELETE is working... put this on top of your file: error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

Comment: add exclamtion sign in isset call near delete_item_id